# Rails3 + Devise + Sign_in + Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i have a simple controller where i want to log user manually and for some reason devise method sign_in is not working

Here is my controller:

```
class Brand::ChallengesController < ApplicationController

 def sign_in
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if user and user.valid_password?(params[:password])
    sign_in(:user, user)
    redirect_to brand_challenges_url
  else
    ...
  end
end
...
```

**edit :**
I always get this answer on the sign_in method:

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
```

It seems that i only can use this method within a devise child class.
I tried to include many Devise helpers but nothing it working for the moment.

Comment: Hi - where are you getting the error? can you give us the full stacktrace (especially the exact line-number that is causing the error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sign_in
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if user and user.valid_password?(params[:password])
    sign_in(:user, user)
    ^^^^^^^
```

See that line.
You are calling `sign_in` - which is the name of method that you just wrote.
Which means your code is calling itself... and your `sign_in` method has zero parameters.

(If you took away the `(:user, user)` part... you'd actually get a stack overflow - because your code would call itself... which would call itself... over and over until the memory just exploded and died).

Are you trying to call some *other* method called `sign_in` ? if so - where is that method located?

Comment: My God ... Must be really tired. I believe the problem is in the method name ... Gonna give this a try right now and comeback to you
Thx